# blank black when opening xml preview and it becomes slow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

my android studio preview xml blank black when opening xml preview and it becomes slow, i am using android studio 4.2, mac os catalina 10.15.7, please help me

[image]

Comment: you have the solution??

Answer (score 0):

This problem also happened to me, try-

1.closing the project and re-opening it

2.enable/disable the new rendering engine

3.go to your project files, check in res->values-> themes, there must be two files, first one "themes.xml" other one "themes.xml/night"
Check if both of them  exist and doesn't have any errors.